# Avoiding Android Studio and SDK downloads

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Android Studio and SDK downloads are just so often that our network gets chocked by everyone trying to download the updates.

Is there a place I can download all components regularly, and request all people within our network to just replicate locally from a local repository ?